# Deserialize multi level JSON Array of objects to C# classes

Tags: json, c#-4.0, serialization

I am new to JSON and having difficulty do deserialize a JSON feed from an API. I use JSON.NET from Newtonsoft. The JSON below shows a product containing media as well. I can access the product info, id, cnk, name, etc... without a problem. But the problem is about the media structure. Media contains arrays with the name "450x450" and "900x900". Of each type there can be one, multiple objects or even none.

the JSON feed:

`

```
{
"products" : [
    {
      "id": 44649,
      "cnk": "2753982",
      "language": "nl",
      "last_updated_at": "2015-12-10T15:19:51+0000",
      "status": "active",
      "name": "EUCERIN tube",
      "febelco_name": "EUCERIN tube 2",
      "ean": "4005000019875",
      "apb_category": "cosmetics",
      "weight": 62,
      "width": 38,
      "height": 126,
      "depth": 49,
      "prescription": false,
      "tax": 21,
      "public_price_apb": 7.8,
      "public_price_febelco": 12.9,

      "media": {
        "450x450": [
          {
            "id": 26587,
            "path": "media\/450x450\/19e09206ae752105101d2235935959ab4b085869.jpg",
            "file_path": "media\/450x450\/19e09206ae752105101d2235935959ab4b085869.jpg",
            "image_type": "packshot",
            "last_updated_at": "2015-11-16T00:00:00+0000"
          }
        ],
        "900x900": [
          {
            "id": 26587,
            "path": "media\/900x900\/f24fb9a2c308ff091addf6c3f744850004962d6f.jpg",
            "file_path": "media\/900x900\/f24fb9a2c308ff091addf6c3f744850004962d6f.jpg",
            "image_type": "packshot",
            "last_updated_at": "2015-11-16T00:00:00+0000"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ]

}
```

`

I am using VS2013 and I used the custom class creator function:

`EDIT -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes`

this gives the following classes:

```
public class MediProduct
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cnk { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public DateTime last_updated_at { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string ean { get; set; }
    public string apb_category { get; set; }
    public bool prescription { get; set; }
    public int tax { get; set; }
    public float public_price_apb { get; set; }
    public float public_price_febelco { get; set; }
    public Consumer_Categories[] consumer_categories { get; set; }
    public Media media { get; set; }
    public string febelco_name { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int depth { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    }

public class Media
{
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "450x450")]
public _450X450[] _450x450 { get; set; }
public _900X900[] _900x900 { get; set; }
}

public class _450X450
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string path { get; set; }
public string file_path { get; set; }
public string image_type { get; set; }
public DateTime last_updated_at { get; set; }
}

public class _900X900
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string path { get; set; }
public string file_path { get; set; }
public string image_type { get; set; }
public DateTime last_updated_at { get; set; }
}
```

So I have to get the "media" item where I can have multiple "450x450" objects containing the data I want. I do not know how to get to this level and especially how I can get rid of the `object reference is not set to an instance of an object` error. I tried the following things:

`

```
 //Get JSON result objects into a list
            IList<JToken> results = PartProduct["products"].Children().ToList();

            //serialize JSON results into .net objects

            //IList<UsefulProduct> ReturnProducts = new List<UsefulProduct>();
            IList<MediProduct> ReturnProducts = new List<MediProduct>();




            //add the different products to the list
            foreach (JToken result in results)
            {
                //UsefulProduct usefulProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsefulProduct>(result.ToString()); 
                MediProduct MyProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MediProduct>(result.ToString());
                if (null == result["description"])
                {
                    MyProduct.description  = "/";
                }


                    dynamic Rommel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<_450X450[]>(result["450x450"].ToString());
                    //Console.WriteLine(StommeFoto._450x450.id);  



                ReturnProducts.Add(MyProduct);

            }
```

But there is no way I can access the data in the media objects. Please help!

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. When addressing a Json Object in an object like the code below:

```
    "media": {
            "450x450": [
              {
                "id": 26587,
                "path": "media\/450x450\/19e09206ae752105101d2242935959ab4b074869.jpg",
                "file_path": "media\/450x450\/19e09206ae752105101d2242935959ab4b074869.jpg",
                "image_type": "packshot",
                "last_updated_at": "2015-11-16T00:00:00+0000"
              }
            ],
            "900x900": [
              {
                "id": 26587,
                "path": "media\/900x900\/f24fb9a2c308ff091adbc6c3f744850005962d6f.jpg",
                "file_path": "media\/900x900\/f24fb9a2c308ff091adbc6c3f744850005962d6f.jpg",
                "image_type": "packshot",
                "last_updated_at": "2015-11-16T00:00:00+0000"
              }
            ]
          }
```

there is a "media" object containing 2 arrays, one type "450x450" and the other of type "900x900. So to address this data you have to address the proper child.

```
  //Get JSON result objects into a list
            IList<JToken> results = PartProduct["products"].Children().ToList();

            //serialize JSON results into .net objects

            //IList<UsefulProduct> ReturnProducts = new List<UsefulProduct>();
            IList<MediProduct> ReturnProducts = new List<MediProduct>();




            //add the different products to the list
            foreach (JToken result in results)
            {

                MediProduct MyProduct = new MediProduct();
                MyProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MediProduct>(result.ToString());
                if (null == result["description"])
                {
                    MyProduct.description = "/";
                }

                if (null != result["media"]["450x450"])
                {
                    //to get the picture array. You have to address the correct path, in this case ["media"] "[450x450]
                    _450X450[] Foto450x450 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<_450X450[]>(result["media"]["450x450"].ToString());
                    _900X900[] Foto900x900 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<_900X900[]>(result["media"]["900x900"].ToString());
}

}
```

By searching in the result["media"]["450x450"] subset I was able to get the data in the proper array. 
I also found that the following statement, in my class definition was holding back the data:

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]

I found this statement somewhere on this forum. But it was not doing what I wanted. I commented this out and I could access my data!

regards,